# How to properly set up a table in mysql and write a sql query in node.js for json data

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I have a node.js script that saves it's data to a *.json file. I am trying to convert this to save the data into a mysql db. I have tried setting the table name as pendingPaymentList and using column names as accounts, accountId, shares, and using json by type, but everything is returned as [object object] or null. I have also tried using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but no luck.

As you can see, I am unsure of how to create my table & columns as well as to write a sql query to process the data. I want each column in the table to store each different field in the json array so that I may select them and display each column later.  Below is saved input of the JSON data, save function and mysql con info with query.

```
/* example: { "pendingPaymentList": { "16021258545754610851": 2.17 }

*/

"pendingPaymentList": { "int": int }}
```

Save function

```
module.exports = {
updateByNewBlock: updateByNewBlock,
getStoredBalance: getStoredBalance,
getPendingBalance: getPendingBalance,
getBalance: getBalance,
saveSession: saveSession,
getAccountPending: getAccountPending,
loadSession: function (done) {
    if (fs.existsSync('pool-payments.json')) {
        fs.readFile('pool-payments.json', function (err, data) {
            try {
                var loadedData = JSON.parse(data);

                if (loadedData.hasOwnProperty('blockPaymentList')) {
                    blockPaymentList = loadedData.blockPaymentList;
                }
                if (loadedData.hasOwnProperty('pendingPaymentList')) {
                    pendingPaymentList = loadedData.pendingPaymentList;
                }
                if (loadedData.hasOwnProperty('sentPaymentList')) {
                    sentPaymentList = loadedData.sentPaymentList;
                    if (sentPaymentList.length > poolConfig.maxRecentPaymentHistory) {
                        var toRemove = sentPaymentList.length - poolConfig.maxRecentPaymentHistory;
                        sentPaymentList.splice(0, toRemove);
                    }
```

and con info:

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 var database = mysql.createConnection({
 host: 'host',
 user: 'user',
 password: 'password',
 database: 'database'
});
database.connect(function(connectionError){
if(connectionError){
throw connectionError;
}
var sql = "INSERT INTO pendingPaymentList(payments) VALUES ('" + JSON.parse(data) + "')";
database.query(sql, function(queryError, queryResult){
if(queryError){
  throw queryError;
  }
 });
});
```

I'm really only concerned with the pendingPaymentList array until I can get it to store json data correctly and output it, then I will work on the blockPaymentList and sentPaymentList